# Check the most frequent letter(s) in a word. Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

My task is:

To write a function that gets a string as an argument and returns the letter(s) with the maximum appearance in it.

Example 1:

```
s = 'Astana'
```

Output:

```
a
```

Example 2:

```
s = 'Kaskelen'
```

Output:

```
ke
```

So far, I've got this [code](https://repl.it/repls/ElderlyDentalTest)(click to run):

```
a = input()


def most_used(w):

    a = list(w)
    indexes = []
    g_count_max = a.count(a[0])

    for letter in a:
        count = 0
        i = int()
        for index in range(len(a)):
            if letter == a[index] or letter == a[index].upper():
                count += 1
                i = index
        if g_count_max <= count:       //here is the problem.
            g_count_max = count
            if i not in indexes:
                indexes.append(i)


    letters = str()

    for i in indexes:
        letters = letters + a[i].lower()

    return letters

print(most_used(a))
```

The problem is that it automatically adds first letter to the array because the sum of appearance of the first element is actually equal to the starter point of appearance(which is basically the first element).

Example 1:

```
s = 'hheee'
```

Output:

```
he
```

Example 2:

```
s = 'malaysia'
```

Output:

```
ma
```

Comment: check out Counter.. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to can be much simplified by using the standard library's [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object

```
from collections import Counter
def most_used(word):
    # this has the form [(letter, count), ...] ordered from most to least common
    most_common = Counter(word.lower()).most_common()
    result = []
    for letter, count in most_common:
        if count == most_common[0][1]:
            result.append(letter) # if equal largest -- add to result
        else:
            break  # otherwise don't bother looping over the whole thing
    return result  # or ''.join(result) to return a string
```

Comment: @Idlehands In order to handle the case where there are equally common letters i.e. `aabb`

Comment: @FHTMitchell Thank you man. This works perfectly! Appreciate your help, but didn't truly understand line: if count == most_common[0][1]:

Comment: `most_common[0]` is a tuple of the form `(letter, count)` which represents the (equal) most common `letter` and how many times it appears in the word (`count`). Therefore `most_common[0][1]` is the count that a letter must have in order to be the equal most common. We loop through the counter and find all letters that are equal most common by comparing with the first (which we know is one of these (or maybe the only) most common).

Comment: @FHTMitchell thank you so much! So this is the same as: `if g_count_max <= count` in my code

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with a list comprehension and `max()`:

```
s = 'Kaskelen'

s_lower = s.lower() #convert string to lowercase

counts = {i: s_lower.count(i) for i in s_lower}

max_counts = max(counts.values()) #maximum count

most_common = ''.join(k for k,v in counts.items() if v == max_counts)
```

Yields:

```
'ke'
```

Comment: Modified to allow for multiple letters to be returned as a string.

Comment: More comments ;) -- Your most_common is `O(n^2)` because you are iterating over counts in `max` every iteration of the list comprehension. `s.lower()` should probably be a variable rather than repeat calling. Also if you're joining an iterable, make it a generator comprehension `(...)` rather than a list `[...]`.

Comment: No doubt, I think your solution is superior. Just another option for the OP that doesn't require importing another library :) I'll make those modifications, appreciate your input!

Comment: Thanks :) but I'm just trying to help -- you could solve all these just with assignments `s_lower = s.lower()`, `max_counts = max(counts.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code using list comprehensions:

```
word = input('word=').lower()
letters = set(list(word))
max_w = max([word.count(item) for item in letters])
out = ''.join([item for item in letters if word.count(item)==max_w])
print(out)
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can import Counter lib:

```
from collections import Counter

a = "dagsdvwdsbd"

print(Counter(a).most_common(3)[0][0])
```

Then it returns:

```
d
```